# Serviceworker event.respondWith network error

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I running my radio site, and just created service-worker.js and it works, but when I go first time on the site, html5 audio works, but then if I don't clear cookies and site data, it won't work and this error comes out in console:

( I need always clear site data, if I wanna hear music )

> Failed to load ‘http://myradio.com:8000/radio’. A ServiceWorker passed
> a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with ‘TypeError:
> NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.’.

Service-worker.js

```js
var cacheName = 'Myradio';
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.php',
  '/assets/css/all.min.css',
  '/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
  '/assets/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',
  '/main.js'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) { 
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

HTML

```html
<audio id="myAudio" preload="metadata">
   <source src="http://myradio.com:8000/radio" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Service workers are required to have a secure origin hosted on "https".  I assume your site has that since you can register your service worker.

The problem arises when you attempt to make the request to "http://myradio.com:8000/radio".  This is an "http:" URL and not to a secure origin.  When you do this in a page you will get a "mixed content" warning in the browser UI.

Mixed content, however, is not permitted at all in a service worker.  Making a fetch() call to an "http:" URL from a service worker script will return a NetworkError.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Host the radio stream on https.
2. Check for the http URL before calling respondWith() and early return from the service worker script.

Option (2) is probably less work here.  Something like:

```js
/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  // we cannot fetch mixed-content from a service worker, so early return
  if (e.request.url.startsWith('http:'))
    return;

  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```